# Functools reduce killed error while joining multiple txt files with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Following my question ([Join multiple txt files into one file using pd.DataFrame.join()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66278382/join-multiple-txt-files-into-one-file-using-pd-dataframe-join)) I tried this code, which works perfectly well with a subset of files:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
from functools import reduce
path = r'/path/to/my/txt' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")
my_dfs = []
my_dfs = [pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t').set_index('POS') for file in all_files]
reduce(lambda l,r: l.combine_first(r), my_dfs)
my_dfs.to_csv('result.txt', sep="\t")
```

But when I try to join my 30-50 files I get the following error:

```
Killed
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this like that, obviously suggestions to improve/find errors are welcome.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
from functools import reduce
path = r'/path/to/my/txt' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")
my_dfs = [pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t').set_index(['POS', 'CHROM', 'REF', 'ALT']) for file in all_files]
df = pd.concat(my_dfs, axis=1)
result_df = df.fillna('.')
result_df.to_csv('result.txt', sep="\t")
```